# Unable to upload file using webdriver onto Box.com

Tags: java, selenium, upload, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am failing to automate upload onto Box.com

Tried Multiple options listed below. None of them seem to help -

```
driver.findElement(By.id("upload_file1")).sendKeys("C:\\Automation\\BoxUploadFile.rtf");
driver.findElement(By.id("upload_file1")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/input")).click();
```

And numerous others...

Also, there is no error thrown by webdriver.

Comment: This is now working. Parent element has to be hovered upon before uploading.

Comment: Your question is still showing up in the Unanswered list. If you have found a solution yourself, you should post it as an Answer and accept it; this shows you are not still waiting for an answer.

Comment: I had totally forgotten regarding this. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

The goal was to automate uploads onto Box.com without using AutoIT.

@id=upload_file1 is the element against which the filename has to be sent. This element is not visible by default. A series of actions has to be performed for enabling the visibility of this element

Here is the sequence of steps followed -

```
-> Mouse Hover to @id=upload_button
-> Then you click on the arrow (b[@class='arrow'])
-> Mouse Hover on to linkText = Upload Files
```

Now you can use sendKeys method to populate the fileName onto @id=upload_file1

Voila! Your file is now uploaded!!